# Bad pseudo-random number generator -- any guesses?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I'm trying to diagnose a badly-implemented pseudo-random number generator. The two key features of the bit streams produced by this PRNG are: significant correlation of consecutive bits (approximately 70% of 0's are followed by 0's, and similarly for 1's), and significant anti-correlation of bits that are 17 apart in the stream (correlation coefficient close to -0.6). Are there any obvious guesses for what might be going on here?

Comment: FYI, probably off topic as written (request for cryptanalysis).

Comment: Modular multiplication with a specific value might do it.